# Laravel 6 assigns unwanted variables to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6

In my web application, I'm using a view twice, let me call it `modify-customer.blade.php`. It is used to create new records as well as to edit existing ones. It has completely the same design except text and form input values that are filled from the assigned customer.

In my `edit`-action, I'm assigning the variable "customers" containing a list of customers (because I need other customer data as well, retreived by `$customers = Customer::orderBy('name', 'asc')->get()`):

```
return view('customer.modify-customer', ['customers' => $customers]);
```

In my `new`-action, I'm assigning a single customer record retrieved by `$customer = Customer::where(xyz)->getFirstOrFail();` which is assigned to the view:

```
return view('customer.modify-customer', ['customer' => $customer]);
```

#### The problem is:

I'm able to access variable `$customer` in my `edit` action (which returns the last record from the database table for an unknown reason). I really have no clue why, I never assigned a variable called `customer` to it. I only assigned `customers`.

Hope you guys understand what I'm trying to say. Thank you for your help; I really appreciate an idea how to disable or fix this .

Comment: you probably have a `foreach ($customers as $customer)` in your template ... so you have a `$customer` variable created by the loop, which if it runs completely will contain the last record in that collection

Comment: Show your view, so we can confirm @lagbox theory.

Comment: I can confirm @lagbox theory. But $customer should only be available within the foreach-loop, isn't it?

Comment: unfortunately not, PHP does not scope variables that way ... `$customer` will exist outside of the loop as long as the loop has ran at all

Comment: @lagbox Okay, that makes sense, but I didn't found this note in laravels documentation yet. I fixed my problem by renaming variables. Thank you for your help!

Comment: because its a PHP thing not Laravel ... the only part about the loop that is Laravel specific is that Laravel creates a `$loop` variable for you to access when using Blade

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you order the routes properly

```
/edit
/:id
```

constants before variables, this way it catches the `edit` route before before the `view` route.